# import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

This is the error i am seeing when i add  "simple_permissions" package. How can i fix this? I recently upgraded flutter and it used to work very well before the upgrade.
/root/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_permissions-0.1.9/android/src/main/java/com/ethras/simplepermissions/SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

```
/root/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_permissions-0.1.9/android/src/main/java/com/ethras/simplepermissions/SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

  symbol:   class ActivityCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
/root/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_permissions-0.1.9/android/src/main/java/com/ethras/simplepermissions/SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:10: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
                                 ^
/root/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_permissions-0.1.9/android/src/main/java/com/ethras/simplepermissions/SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:156: error: cannot find symbol
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, perm, 0);
        ^
  symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin
/root/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_permissions-0.1.9/android/src/main/java/com/ethras/simplepermissions/SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:163: error: cannot find symbol
        return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
  symbol:   variable ContextCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin
/root/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_permissions-0.1.9/android/src/main/java/com/ethras/simplepermissions/SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(registrar.activity(), permission)) {
                ^
  symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin
/root/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_permissions-0.1.9/android/src/main/java/com/ethras/simplepermissions/SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(registrar.context(), permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ^
  symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin
6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':simple_permissions:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
[!] Flutter tried to create the file `android/settings_aar.gradle`, but failed.
To manually update `settings.gradle`, follow these steps:
    1. Copy `settings.gradle` as `settings_aar.gradle`
    2. Remove the following code from `settings_aar.gradle`:
        def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
        def properties = new Properties()
        assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
        localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
Exception: Please create the file and run this command again.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: try to run `flutter clean`

Comment: well, still same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to check the package before using it.

It seems that `simple_permissions` is outdated and this package hasn't been updated since 2018 and its repository is gone from github, consider using other package like [`permission_handler`](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler).

Cheers.